# PHP/SQL Variable manipulation

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following variables:

```
$days_a = $array_total['days']; // This one display days 
$hours_a = $array_total['hours']; // This one display hours
$minutes_a = $array_total['minutes']; // This one display minutes
$seconds_a = $array_total['seconds']; // This one display seconds
```

These variables give me the current session time, here all works.

Now the problem...

I have then these variables:

```
$days_f = $fetch_s['days'];
$hours_f = $fetch_s['hours'];
$minutes_f = $fetch_s['minutes'];
$seconds_f = $fetch_s['seconds'];
```

These display the time that the user entered in the website previously, they took the values from the database... I did this for add the current session variable values to the values in the MySQL Db:

```
   $days_2 = $days_a + $days_f;
   $hours_2 = $hours_a + $hours_f;
   $minutes_2 = $minutes_a + $minutes_f;
   $seconds_2 = $seconds_a + $seconds_f;
```

But I need that each 60 seconds it add 1 to $minutes_2 , each 60 minutes it add 1 to $hours_2 and each 24 hours it add 1 to $days_2

For example if I have 118 seconds I need that it adds 1 to $minutes_2 and set the variable $seconds_2 to 58 etc...

How can this be done?

I tried something like that:

```
   $seconds = $seconds_2 % 60;
    $minutes_3  = $seconds_2 / 60;
     $minutes  = $minutes_3  % 60;
      $hours_3   = $minutes  / 60;
       $hours    = $hours_3  % 24;
        $days   = $hours  / 24;

          $days = (int)$days_int;
```

But this won't work... Someone know how do that in a similar or different way?

Could someone give me the code? Please

Comment: See the examples for DateTime::diff() [here](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Answer (score 2):

In my experience it is easier to do these calculations by converting to UNIX seconds for a given time, adding the seconds, the converting back. That way the system does all the day, hour, minute and seconds book-keeping for you. Use e.g. mktime to convert to UNIX seconds (you can use your existing time parameters), and date, strftime to convert back to day, hour, minutes, seconds.

Comment: I second this answer. Personally, I never even store the data/time written out as a string. I always use UNIX seconds/a UNIX timestamp. Store the timestamp in your database and when necessary, you can easily convert it from a timestamp to a human-readable date/time. By doing this, time modifying arithmetic is made simpler. This also allows you to easily manage timezones by simply converting the UNIX timestamp to whichever timezone you (or a user) would prefer.

Comment: This is how i used to do it in php < 5.3. Now i always use full human readable timestamps (`2014-01-01 00:00:00`) and use `DateTime` to format and perform calculations. Its a lot heavier than unix time stamps but its easier to work with and is more expressive IMO. What the OP is doing however, is just insane.

Comment: Haha, well, the OP is learning. We were all in his shoes at one point.

Anyway, yes, `DateTime` presents better readability, but you gain some advantages with searching the database. You can simply pull up the records of all entries with a timestamp greater than another timestamp. I am unsure if MySQL provides a way to compare string representations of dates and thus perform that same task. I would also imagine that it's more expensive to use `DateTime` vs. simple arithmetic; however, I could be wrong about that.

Comment: I do not understand how do that, could someone give me a code example?